# .htaccess: RewriteBase takes one argument, the base URL of the per-directory context,

Tags: php, .htaccess

when I run this application on localhost it works properly but when try to run it through server it shows 500 Internal Server Error my error log shows

```
.htaccess: RewriteBase takes one argument, the base URL of the per-directory context,
```

my htacces file is

```html
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /jayshrikrishna

# Prevent CI index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L] 

# Prevent user access to the CI system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L] 

# Prevent user access to the CI application folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: What you want setting RewriteBase  without anything?

Comment: Few people ever need to use `RewriteBase`. It merely makes sense within subfolders below the document root, or if the hoster has set up fancy virtual hosting base path rewriting schemes.